# How to add an exit / return TransitionAdapter

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm creating a scene transition using to move from Activity A to Activity B:

```
ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
```

In Activity B I add a TransitionAdapter to perform certain tasks when the scene transition is completed:

```
getWindow().getEnterTransition().addListener(...)
```

Is there a way to add a TransitionAdapter to the exit / return in Activity B so I can disable a video playing before the scene transition starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution. Instead of adding a TransitionAdapter to detect when the Activity was about to start the Scene Transition, I now explicitly clean up my Activity and then call "finishAfterTransition" to start the animation.

e.g.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

      // PERFORM SOME ACTION

      finishAfterTransition();
      return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }
```